# Ошибка преобразования char в int

Tags: c++

Имеется следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "big_int.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *num = "124141414141444134";
    big_int a;

    cout << (int)num[0] << endl;

    a = num;

    cout << a;
}
```

Проблема в том, что выводится (первый `cout`) не 0-ой символ, т.е. `1`, а число `49`...

Comment: Ну вы же сами попросили выводить `int`, то есть не символ `'1'` а числовое значение константы `'1'`. А это и есть `49` на вашей платформе. Уберите оттуда приведение к `(int)` и будет выводиться символ `'1'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Число `49` соответствует коду символа `'1'` в таблице ASCII.

То есть внутренне в машине символ `'1'` хранится в виде данного кода, А, например, в таблице EBCDIC символу `'1'` соответствует код `241`.

Если вы хотите вывести именно 1, то вам следует либо написать просто

```
cout << num[0] << endl;
```

либо

```
cout << num[0] - '0' << endl;
```

Имейте в виду, что строковые литералы имеют тип константных символьных массивов. Поэтому необходимо добавить квалификатор `const` в объявлении

```
const char *num = "124141414141444134";
```

Comment: Воу, спасибо большое, а нет никакой низкоуровневой или битовой операции для этого дела? Ради интереса спрашиваю, вдруг пригодится.

Comment: @kot_mapku3 Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Ну, он же сам преобразовывает символ '0' в int и потом проводит операцию вычитания, хотя '0' в ASC2 это код 48

Comment: @kot_mapku3 Когда используется бинарный оператор минус, то операнды приводятся к типу Int, если они по рангу меньше, чем тип int. Поэтому это стандартный прием перевести любой цифровой символ в целочисленное значение, которое он означает, написав c - '0'

Comment: Значит бинарный... Спасибо)